# Upgrade ruby to 2.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, ruby-upgrade

I have upgraded Ruby to version 2.4.0 in my Rails app, but when I try to `bundle install`, I face with the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before
```

Comment: Can you show full log message?

Comment: Did you try `$ bundle update json` and then bundle it up again?

Comment: yes but it did not fixed

Comment: How did you update Ruby? Did you verify that you actually run the new version? How did you install `bundler`? Did you follow the instructions in the error message after the installation of `json` failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json(1.8.3)` is not compatible with ruby `2.4.0`. Try using a newer version.

`$ bundle update json`

Comment: Thanks Hossein :D